# How to access a static variable from Parent form to child form in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, static, static-members

How can I access static variable from Parent form to child form?

Comment: What part of the documentation for `static` didn't answer your question?

Comment: I didn't get you.. What you mean?

Comment: Why I get down vote for this question?

Comment: My first form contain a array                                   Public static byte[] value=new byte[10]; I want to access this from form3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just use the Class Name, in this case Form1 to access your variable.

In your Form1 Class you would declare it as such.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static  byte[] value=new byte[10]; 
    Form2 f2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 ....
```

and you would access it in Form3 like this:

```
Form1.value;
```

Note the Class name in this case, not the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Static members are defined for the whole type not just a specific instance. So, in your case, you don't need a reference to parent form to access a static member. The only condition is that the member should be visible (i.e. not `private`). It should be something like this:

```
class ParentForm : Form
{
    public static string Name = "SomeName";
}

class ChildForm : Form
{
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        var parentName = ParentForm.Name;
    }
}
```